# "Cannot set headers after they are sent" Passport js on successredirect

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passport-local and express. In my app.js I have:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    { usernameField: 'email' },
        function(email, password, done) {
            if(users=='') {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            users.find((user) => {
                user.validPassword = (pwd) => {
// password is plain text for the purpose of practicing
                    if(pwd===user.password) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                if(user.email!==email) {
                    console.log("email: " + email)
                    console.log("user: " + user.email)
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
                }
                if(!user.validPassword(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            },
            passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
                done(null, user);
            }),
            
            passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
                done(null, user);
            })
        )
    })
);
```

and

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local',
    {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true,
    }
));
```

When I register once and sign in, everything's fine.
But when I register the second time and sign in, the error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

is rendered.

But when I remove the success and failure redirects, the website works fine regardless of how many users registered(but of course I have to manually visit the next page).

How can I use success and failure redirect while not getting the error?

Thanks